# Need some good 'JavaScript for ASP.NET developers' books and blogs, since AJAX UpdatePanels are performance killers

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

Regarding those articles:

- [Update Panels and JSON Alternatives](http://csharp-codesamples.com/2009/06/update-panels-and-json-alternatives/)
- [Why ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanels are dangerous](http://encosia.com/2007/07/11/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/)
- [PageMethods vs UpdatePanels](http://izlooite.blogspot.com/2010/06/pagemethods-vs-updatepanels.html)

I think AJAX UpdatePanels can't be the appropriate way of implementing a partial page renders for big application or good scalable ones.

So I hope I could find a dedicated sources for search things.
I know how to integrate JavaScript with ASP.NET
But what I'm looking for is a very specific resource to teach me to do whatever I could have done with AJAX UpdatePanels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a (thankfully brief) affair with UpdatePanels, and since I've started using jQuery http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials and jQuery UI  http://jqueryui.com/
I have never looked back. I know this isnt a book but I found that most of the stuff on the website is pretty well written and can get you started pretty fast :)

I think the idea is you want to start looking to have your client consume server data with as little asp.net heavy handedness as possible.

I think this works alot better in ASP.NET MVC than it did in previous platforms.

Comment: "I had a (thankfully brief) affair with UpdatePanels, and since I've started using jQuery http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials and jQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/ I have never looked back." +1 for that =D. but did you tried WebMethods ? -it looks good too- and unfortunately i'm using Web Forms!

Comment: I hadn't really messed with it -- sorry. That aside, I think if you replace your updatepanel usage with $.ajax() calls, its definately a big step in the right direction. Take a look here http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/  You can use $.ajax() to call a page method directly and render the results to your page.

Comment: Good article, I found it earlier while googling about UPDATE PANEL alternatives. TBH I was hoping for a good and complete reference to help me with JavaScript learning not just specific and basic introduction to the subject. but this is so far an acceptable answer. Thanks Yablargo for your time =)